# Derivation of the Maurer-Cartan formula

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

The left-invariant Maurer-Cartan forms are given by
$$g^{-1}dg, $$
where $g$ is a Lie group $G$ to $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

My question is why is
$$d(g^{-1}dg)=(g^{-1}dg)\wedge(g^{-1}dg)\quad ? $$
How come one gets an exterior product out of an exterior derivative?

Comment: "wher g is an element of a Lie group G." I'm pretty certain that in this context, $g$ is not an element of a Lie group. Rather, it is probably a map from $G$ to $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I've changed it.

Comment: It might be clearer to write this in terms of the components of $g$ and its inverse $h = g^{-1}$. But a key fact is that  a scalar function can be moved from one factor of the wedge product to another, $$(\theta f)\wedge\phi = \theta\wedge(f\phi).$$

Answer (score 1):

$g^{-1}g=1$, so $dg^{-1}g+g^{-1}dg=0$, hence $dg^{-1}=-g^{-1}dg\cdot g^{-1}$.
Thus $d(g^{-1}dg)=d(g^{-1})\wedge dg=-g^{-1}dg\cdot g^{-1}\wedge dg=g^{-1}dg\wedge g^{-1}dg$

Comment: These are the steps I understand, but why do you place a wedge $d(g^{−1}dg)=d(g^{−1})\wedge dg$?

Comment: These are basic properties for exterior derivatives. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative